# Как организовать Приход/Списание/ Продажа/ Остатки на складе MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть своя разработка по программе доставки, работает уже около года и всех устраивает. Решил дальше развиваться и написать софт для розницы.

В общем есть задача хранить остатки, делать приходы и списания ( там еще куча другого, но пока это интересует)
Пока делаю складской учет. Компания занимается приготовлением еды и продажей ее в розницу и на доставку.

Весь функционал работы с заказом и т.д уже есть, просто надо сделать блок учета. С 1С пробывали связаться, кучу API Надо доделывать и в итоге постоянно не согласованность у нас. Поэтому решили сами написать. Все есть, кроме грамотной архитектуры базы для учета именно.

Много прочитал информации в интернете и материалов на форумах и похожие вопросы мои, но у всех разная специфика и каждый по своему делает

Пока пришел к такому:
-Хранить остатки в отдельной таблице с привязкой на торговую точку и на продукт
- Одна таблица для приемки товара ( там еще связные есть , список продуктов и т.д)
- Одна таблица для списания товара ( там еще связные есть , список продуктов и т.д)
- Одна таблица для продажи

В общем есть сомнения в реализации, особенно с хранением остатков, особенно когда меняют задним числом, либо в приемке старой поменяли количество.

Да и в общем, эффективно хранить остатки в отдельной таблице или стоит просто делать приход-расход-продажи

А может вообще объединить приход/списание/продажа и тогда остатки проще считать, но таблица получится при таком подходе просто огромная и подсчет остатков будет трудоемкой операцией.

В общем хотел у Вас спросить, может кто то работает с программами учета, есть какие удачные реализации? Я не жду развернутого ответа с описанием таблиц и т.д. Мне просто нужно узнать направление куда двигаться, так как на разных источниках говорят по разному

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оправдала себя концепция, которую я кратко изложу.

Нужно сделать таблицу операций. У операций должно быть три типа:

1. Приход
2. Расход
3. Ревизия

Которые в свою очередь могут "ветвиться" на виды приходов, расходов и ревизий.

У каждой операции должен быть флаг "Подтверждена" или "Не подтверждена". Подтверждённую операцию менять можно только через руководство.

И есть подчиненная таблица "Товары в операции" - id товара и количество.

При подтверждении операции должен формироваться документ, который нужно хранить, например, в HTML.

В этом случае расчётное количество на складе легко считается: последняя подтверждённая ревизия *плюс*  подтверждённые приходы после последней ревизии *минус* подтверждённые расходы после последней ревизии.

Comment: Получается у Вас есть таблица приходов/расходов/ревизий и таблица движения товара,  где находится [ид_товара,склад,количество, тип_операции] , я правильно понял ?

Comment: Денис Захаренко Да, верно